Why Big-O has same direction inequality as little-o?
Wikipedia article states, that ..."f(x) is little-o of g(x)" means that $g(x)$ grows much faster than $f(x)$. $f(x)=o(g(x))\text{ as }x\to \infty$ if for every positive constant ε there exists a constant $ x_{0}$ such that $|f(x)|\leq \varepsilon g(x)\text{ for all }x\geq x_{0}.$
For example, one has $2x=o(x^{2})$ and $1/x=o(1),$  both as $x\to\infty .$ Consider it please for $x\to x_0$, so the condition is $0<|x-x_0|\delta$, and requires some delta to exist, as I assume.
Question 1 - how can $y=1$ grow faster than $y=1/x$, if $y=1$ does not grow at all?
Question 2 - why Big-O definition also requires $f(x)$ be smaller than $g(x)$ multiplied by some coefficient? I understand, that the difference, is that in case of little-o it should be true for all $\epsilon$, and for Big-O at least for one (though do not currently get why), but why also less, and not greater?
Question 3 (extra) - in my book stated:
Let $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ be infinitively small functions at $x->x_0$. If $\lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=0$, it is called, that $f(x)$ is infinitively small of higher order, compare to $g(x)$ and denotes $f = o(g)$.
It is because, for numbers $(0,1)$ squares and other (>1) powers gives values smaller than original, so it means, that, for example $f(x)=x^3-3$ and $g(x)=x^2-3$? But definition requires it to be true for any $\epsilon$. Is not  $f(x)=x^3-3$ for not $x>1$ growth faster?

"how can $y=1$ grow faster than $y=1/x$, if $y=1$ does not grow at all?" Well, $1/x$ is decreasing, or "growing" smaller.. So it's like asking "How can -1 be smaller than 0, when 0 is nothing?"

@JairTaylor, okay, negative velocity (and negative acceleration) is meant, as I understand

Intuitively, it is helpful to think of the relationship between little-o and big-O as analogous to the relationship between $<$ and $\le$.

@isagsadvb not negative acceleration. The "acceleration" of $1/x$ is obviously strictly positive for $x>0$

I'll begin by saying that little-o is a special case of big-O. Intuivitely, we say that $f(x) = \mathcal O(g(x))$ as $x\to x_0$ iff $g(x)$ grows at least as fast as $f(x)$.
On the other hand, we say that $f(x) = o(g(x))$ as $x\to x_0$ iff $g(x)$ grows strictly faster than $f(x)$.
When we're talking about functions approaching $0$, one usually says that a $\mathcal O(f(x))$ is a function which approaches $0$ at least as fast as $f(x)$, which still means it grows slower, but in a clearer way. The same concept is applied to $o(f(x))$, which is usually said to approach $0$ strictly faster than $f(x)$.
So $f(x) = o(g(x)) \implies f(x) = \mathcal O(g(x))$ (but the converse does not hold in general).
Let's now answer your questions.
Question 1. We could say that $y=1/x$ "grows negatively" (aka. decreases) approaching $0$, while the rate of growth of $y=1$ is just $0$. Thus, the rate of growth of the latter is greater. A better way to think about it is that in this case the little-o notation indicates that $y=1/x$ approaches $0$ faster that $y=1$ (which doesn't at all). Usually, you use big-O and little-o to compare functions having similar behavior (usually both approaching $0$ or $\infty$).
Question 2. The reason is quite simple: $f(x)$ being a $\mathcal O(g(x))$ means that $f(x)$ is bounded above by $g(x)$ up to a constant factor (which doesn't mean that $f(x)$ is smaller than $g(x)$), while $f(x)$ being a $o(g(x))$ means that $f(x)$ must be bounded above by any function that is proportional to $g(x)$.
Question 3. This question shows poor understanding of limits, rather than big-O and little-o notations. Consider the following limit:
$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \lim_{x\to0}\frac{x^3}{x^2}$$
Our goal is to show that this limit equals $0$. That is, for any neighborhood of $0$ in the form $I = (-\varepsilon,+\varepsilon)$ we should be able to find another neighborhood of $0$ in the form $J = (-\delta,+\delta)$ such that
$$\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} \in I$$
for any $x \in J$. In other words,
$$-\varepsilon < \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} < \varepsilon \implies -\varepsilon g(x) < f(x) < \varepsilon g(x) \implies |f(x)| < \varepsilon g(x)$$
And this is basically where the little-O definition comes from (I assumed $g(x)>0$).
I think you should go back and study limits better. The example you presented is not valid, because both the functions approach $-3$, not $0$, and the limit of their ratio is $1$, not $0$. In this case we use the notation $f(x)\sim g(x)$, which you should read as "$f(x)$ is asymptotically equivalent to $g(x)$".
If $\varepsilon>1$, you just choose any constant $\delta<1$. Large neighborhood aren't the issue with limits. What we're interested in are small neighborhoods.
I hope I've made the answer clear enough.

I thought Big-o is an opposite to little-o, i.e. $f(x)=o(g(x))$ means, that $f(x)$ is slower, and $f(x)=O(g(x))$ means $f(x)$ is faster.


First You write, that $f(x)=O(g(x))$ means that $g(x))$ is as fast as $f(x)$ or faster, and $f(x)=o(g(x))$ means that $g(x))$ is strictly faster. But in the third paragraph You write, that $o(f(x))$, which is some another $k(x)$, as I understand, is faster than $f(x)$, that should be vice-versa, according to the first statement: $f(x)$ should be strictly faster than $k(x)$, if $k(x) = o(f(x))$. Do I misunderstanding, or it is a typo?



Also You write, that $f(x)=O(g(x))$ means that $g(x)$ at least as fast as $f(x)$, but it is still slower. What "it"? $f(x)$? And whatever, if $g(x)$ growth as fast as $f(x)$ how can $f(x)$ still be slower?


As for the answer to the third question, I have more to comment, and I rather need to create separate post on this, thank You, however

@isagsadvb big-O isn't the opposite of little-o. As I said, little-o is a special case of big-O.

@isagsadvb for your question 1, you have a misconception. When I say "faster" I can mean two things: when talking about functions approaching $\infty$, being "faster" means growing faster (approaching $\infty$ faster). When talking about functions approaching $0$, being "faster" usually means approaching $0$ faster. The meaning depends on the context.

@isagsadvb for question 2, I'm referring to $\mathcal O(f(x))$, if I understand which sentence you're referring to.

@isagsadvb limits aren't a simple topic when studying it for the first time. I'll be happy to clarify any doubts though.
